# Clear *just one* package from NPM cache

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cache

The problem:

sometimes I run

```
npm install x@latest
```

but it doesn't actually pull the latest version of the package (that is lame).

However, if I do:

```
npm cache clean --force && npm install x@latest
```

it will pull the latest

but I actually would rather avoid deleting the whole cache and just delete the cache for a single package, e.g.:

```
npm cache clean x --force
```

but that doesn't seem to be allowed. Anyone know a good workaround?

perhaps simply:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.npm/x
```

?

Comment: You cannot delete only one package. If you look at the docs, they said the following: "There is currently no method exposed through npm to inspect or directly manage the contents of this cache. In order to access it, cacache must be used directly."

Comment: [Here's something that might let you remove cache entries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache-rm)

Answer (score 10):

```sh
> npm cache ls vue@2.6.12
make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue/-/vue-2.6.12.tgz
make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue
make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue
```

> all list item is the cache key, then clean the cache by key

```sh
> npm cache clean make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue/-/vue-2.6.12.tgz

> npm cache clean make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue

> npm cache clean make-fetch-happen:request-cache:https://registry.npmjs.org/vue
```

> or use shell to batch handle

```sh
npm cache ls vue@2.6.12 | xargs npm cache clean
```

Comment: `npm cache ls` is not working with older npm versions (6 and 7, based on the doc. I checked with npm 6.14.16)

Answer (score 1):

I faced that issue, my current workaround is to upgrade the package again. as the `sha` is changed during installation, it will automatically pull the package and update the cache, I tested with `yarn` and it works, haven't tested with `npm` but I assume it will work as expected.

for npm:

```
npm update x@latest
```

for yarn

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

Answer (score 1):

npm cache clean --force
cache clean command will look for the package.json
https://sebhastian.com/npm-clear-cache/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).